# Definition of the tangent space for a submanifold with boundary in terms of regular curves

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces, submanifold

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $M\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and $x\in M$. $\gamma$ is called **curve on $M$ through $x$** if $\gamma:I\to M$ for some nontrivial interval $I\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $0\in I$ and $\gamma(0)=x$. In that case, $\gamma$ is called **regular** if $\left.\gamma\right|_{I^\circ}\in C^1(I^\circ)$ and $\gamma'$ has a continuous extension to $I$.

We know define the tangent space of $M$ at $x$ to be $$T_x\:M:=\left\{\gamma'(0):\gamma\text{ is a regular curve on }M\text{ through }x\right\}.$$

> Am I correct that the reason why we do not simply define a curve to be defined on an **open** interval is that this definition would not yield an appropriate definition of $T_x\:M$ if $M$ is a submanifold **with boundary**? In any case, why is it guaranteed that the extension of $\gamma'$ is unique?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The image of such an open interval w.r.t that curve would not be (relatively) open.
2. It is not. And it doesn't have to be. You only need that all its extensions have the same value $\gamma'(0)$ when extended. Since tangent vectors are an equivalence class of curves at a certain point $p$ having the same derivative (w.r.t. any chart) all these extensions will be equivalent.

Maybe one quick note. If $p$ is a boundary point, then the set of all tangent vectors is just a half space, since there is a missing outward direction. This can be completed by saying, that $T_pM$ is the smallest vector space containing all tangent vectors mentioned above.

Comment: 1.: You mean the image of, for example, $\gamma:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ would not be open in $M$? 2.: But why is the value $\gamma'(0)$ uniquely determined?

Comment: 1. Exactly. Any (non-stationary) curve should be (at least locally) a diffeomorphism from $I:=(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ to $\gamma(I)$. This requires (for inward going curves) that the boundary of $I$ is mapped to the boundary of $\gamma(I)$.
2. Requireing that $\gamma'$ is continuous determines the value at $0$ for any extension since $\gamma'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\gamma'(x)$ holds for continuous functions and hence fully determins the value at $0$ within $I$.